# Displaying swf file in web page using swfobject

Tags: html

I created .html page which loads the swf file using swfobject.The swf file is by default programmed to load in maximized state.Now the problem i am facing is when i launch the swf file in html page shows the maximized content and we need to maximize or minimize the IE to view the swf content in normal state..Is there any way to display the swf content not in maximized state in html page..

Below is my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("TestApplication.swf", "myContent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0");
    </script>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can do it by changing the two values 100% which is for the width and 100% for the height to a lower value. like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("TestApplication.swf", "myContent", "20%", "100%", "9.0.0");
</script>
```

Or alternative you can use http://wiltgen.net/objecty/

Objecty will make your life much simpler.